# array element cannot be displayed

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach

I want to create buttons with car barnds for viber-bot. I got an array of car brands.

```
                                 global $wpdb;
$makes = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'make' ",ARRAY_A);
$makes = $wpdb->get_col( $makes );
$makes = array_unique($makes);
            $buttons = [];
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($makes); $i++)  {
                $buttons[] =
                    (new \Viber\Api\Keyboard\Button())
                        ->setColumns(1)
                        ->setActionType('reply')
                        ->setActionBody($i)
                        ->setText($i);
}
```

This image is displaying 27 buttons (from 0-26)

[buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRjWZ.png)

So there is 27 elements in array. Althought when I'm trying to display 27-th element, it is not displaying:

```
echo $makes[26]
```

Although first and second elements are displaying.

And all elements are displaying with this code

```
foreach ($makes as $make)  {
echo $make; echo ' ';
}
```

When I try to display buttons with foreach, it's not working (my first question)

[all elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WSFH.png)

How ca

Comment: Please don't share debugging information as an image - share them as text. In case of arrays, the best option is `var_export`, since that can be copied directly into an editor to recreate the same array. Please share a `var_export` of `$makes`.

Comment: Side note: you could add `DISTINCT` to your query to avoid having to call `array_unique` afterwards.

Comment: I wrote `DISTINCT` and deleted `array_unique`. It helped, thanks a lot. Can you write my code without `array_unique` and with `DISTINCT` so I can coose it as answer?

Comment: Hm, making that change shouldn't affect your further output. In theory, both should result in the same array.

Comment: @El_Vanja IDK why, but it worked perfectly

Comment: Well, you could dump results to try and understand where the difference happens. Dump `$makes` when using `DISTINCT`, then change your code back and dump it both before and after `array_unique`. That should give you the idea why the output differs.